# Not Showing Outlook Addin

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I have created outlook addin for Outlook 2013 64 bit.

In that Addin, i have created Form region with custom controls.

Then with the reference of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2013/11/21/outlook-deploying-an-outlook-2013-add-in-using-installshield-le.aspx i created setup file for Addin.

Now i installed it in my computer and everything works fine.

However when i try to install it on client computer, it doesn't show addin in outlook.

and i am not able to find any reason.?

I have also created registry for my addins

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the list of installed add-ins? Did you check the required windows registry keys?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have checked all the things. But still it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

If it simply doesn't load, without errors, it only means one thing, outlook is unaware of your addin, cause even when addins are not working, outlook gives you an error or turns the LoadBehaviour regkey to '2'.

On your client, you should check that the registry values are set properly.
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Outlook_PROJECT_ADDIN

[image: Outlook Addin Reg values]

If your addin doesn't work, check to see if those values exist, and if they do, what happens when outlook loads ? does **LoadBehavior** turns to '2' instead of 3 ?

If so, and it works perfectly on your pc,  it probably means you have issues with the Manifest regkey, make sure the manifest points to a valid local location followed by a **|vstolocal**
so its syntax should be something like:

file:///**C:/Outlook_Proj.vsto**|vstolocal

Also make sure you have .Net Framework v4.0 installed on your target PC.

If you're trying to install it to a network drive, make sure you remove the '|vstolocal| thingy, and add the network drive to the trusted zone in Internet Explorer Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following steps will help you solve this problem if you are still facing it.

- Run the deployed setup with administration rights.
- If it is not shown under Add-ins, open the setup folder and double click on the .vsto file then select install.
- If you can see the addin among the others, and is not functioning it means it is disabled. To enable the add-in(since you are using outlook 2013), go to File -> Slow and Disabled Add-ins, and you shold see your add-in on the pop-upped window. Enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the VSTO_SUPRESSDISPLAYALERTS = 0 enviorment variable to get any VSTO alerts. Take a look in the Windows event viewer and off course be sure of being installed the pre requisistes like Office Primary assembles and VSTO for office. Another think, check if your adding was not crashed once and move to inactive add-in list. Search registry for Resiliency key.